# Substitution vs Elimination in Solving Systems of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

When solving systems of equations, is it more efficient in terms of time to solve it using substitution or elimination, and what are your reasons for saying so?

Answer (score 1):

Substitution is faster when you dealing with homogeneous equations and in rest of the cases, elimination is quite faster and efficient.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. How are homogenous systems of equations different to normal stystems of equations?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, elimination. But usually with systems of equations in three or more variables I would use elimination first then substitution afterwards.

Comment: Why would you use both methods? Is that to ensure accuracy?

Comment: Not really. For example, suppose we have a system of three equations in three unknowns. It might be easy to use elimination to obtain solutions for one or two of the variables, and then you can "substitute" your results back into another equation to solve for the remaining variable. See "Gauss Jordan Elimination" for a specific algorithm in solving systems of linear equations. I notice that you have tagged the question as "Linear-Algebra". In that case, you are best off by forming an augmented matrix $\left( A \mid \vec b \right)$ and bringing it into row reduced echelon form to find $\vec x$.